# deparse() with 'else' statement

Tags: r

I am trying to write a shiny app which prints my function code and saves it as a .R file which the I can run to get an desired output.

To get the function code I was using *deparse*. It was getting the job until recently, when one of my function had if else statement. *deparse* tends to separate `else` and `}` and hence if I run the code in the .R file I generate gives an error:

`Error: unexpected 'else' in "else"`

Is there a way to work around this issue?

My sample code is as follows:

```
 MyFunction <- function(dat){
    if(any(dat == 1)){
      print("1 is observed")
    }else{
      print("1 is not present")
    }

  }

  func.string <- deparse(MyFunction)
  codeOfInterest <-func.string[3:8] 
  write(codeOfInterest, "Code.R")
```

Comment: Try with `body` i.e. `body(MyFunction)[[2]]`

Comment: i.e. `deparse(body(MyFunction)[[2]])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
func.string <- capture.output(print(MyFunction))
```

This is the approach I take in the docstring package to gather the source code to be able to detect and extract any documentation comments.